# Ajuda em Python!

Tags: python

Estou travado em uma parte do exercício e precisava que alguém me desse uma luz.

Não tenho certeza se estou fazendo da forma correta mas onde estou com muita dúvida mesmo é em como fazer pra exibir as informações dessa forma:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PJ96.png

```py
codigo = []
resposta = []
gabarito = []
participantes = int(input('Digite a quantidade de participantes: '))
for c in range(0, participantes):
    print('=-'*30)
    codigo.append(int(input('Digite o código do participante: ')))
    questao1 = 0
    print('=-'*30)
    for r in range(0, 10):
        resposta.append(int(input(f'Digite a resposta do participante para a questão {questao1}: ')))
        questao1 += 1
print('=-'*30)
questao2 = 0
for g in range(0,10):
    gabarito.append(int(input(f'Digite o gabarito da questão {questao2}: ')))
```

Answer (score 3):

Para imprimir na mesma linha, utilize o end="".

Então para imprimir as respostas dos participantes ficara assim:

```
    # Número de participantes
    for i in range (0, participantes):
       # Respostas por participantes
       for j in range (0, 10):
          print(resposta[i][j], end="")
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que eu pude entender da pergunta, você quer imprimir esses valores na mesma linha. Em python é possivel imprimir na mesma linha usando o end="" para separar os valores e impedir que quebre a linha o end="" aceita espaços, tabulação ou qualquer outro caractere que você queira

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i ,end=": \t\t")
```